# how, where, and when to best calculate a value to conditionally render react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have a react form (.tsx) that i am making that pre-loads all of a user's account information and then allows them to make edits. i am using a functional component with hooks to handle state. i have a couple elements that will be conditionally rendered based on whether the form has been altered. overall, the isAltered method gets called three times per render. it seems it would be more efficient to calculate and hold the value once per render.  my question is - where, when, and how is the best way to calculate and store this value?

the code that checks for changes:

```
  const isAltered = () => {
    const formValues = Object.keys(values).filter(k => k !== 'passwordConfirm');

    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < formValues.length; i++) {
      let key = formValues[i];
      if (values[key] !== user[key]) {
        return true;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
```

the react elements:

```
<Button
  disabled={!isAltered()}
  className={classes.button}
  type="submit"
/>

<div className={`${isAltered() ? '' : classes.hideDisplay}`}>
   <TextField
       className={classes.textField}
       disabled={!isAltered()}
    />
</div>
```

i tried:

```
  let altered = false;
  useEffect(() => {
    altered = isAltered();
  }, [formValues]);
```

this doesn't work because the "altered" variable loses its value between renders and therefore isn't useful. so i tried storing "altered" in useRef as follows :

```
  let altered = React.useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    altered = isAltered();
  }, [values]);
```

but now "altered" inside of useEffect returns me this error:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject'.>

Comment: you should store `isAltered` result  in the state. And then let the state re-render if changed

Comment: can you explain more? i'm using a functional component with the useState hook to store state.

Comment: If it's never going to change except for if the props change, I'd just add it as a const at the start of the render.

Comment: `useState` is similar for functional components. But in your code you create a reference not a boolean value

Comment: This sounds like something i would set in the form fields' onchange event.  Why wouldn't you just do that?

Comment: @TheMikeInNYC i could move the calculation to onchange, that makes sense - but sorry im still not understanding where to store that value.

Comment: @NikosM.   `let altered = React.useRef(isAltered());` is this what you mean? using this new variable value in place of isAltered() in the components is breaking the functionality

Comment: Change isAltered from a function to a state field. Change your button disabled bindings. Then add onChange for each input field to a function that checks if !state.isAltered then setState isAltered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673520/react-setting-the-disabled-attribute-based-on-a-state